# Downloading files using php

Tags: php, ajax

I am using Wamp server and I have some files placed in the following directory :

> uploads/'firstname' 'lastname' (of each user). (This directory is inside the www folder of Wamp).

I placed the php code for the download in download.php, and I want to use ajax to send the id of the file to be downloaded to download.php

The following is download.php:

```
<?php
require_once ('./db.php');
session_start();

$arrayResult = array();
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = "select Name,OwnerId from fichier where Id = ".$id;
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row['Name'];
$ownerId = $row['OwnerId'];

$query = "select Firstname,Lastname from user where Id = ".$ownerId;
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$firstname = $row['Firstname'];
$lastname = $row['Lastname'];

$path = 'uploads/'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'/';
$download_file =  $path.$name;
error_log(filesize($download_file));
if(file_exists($download_file))
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($download_file).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download_file));
    flush();
    readfile($download_file); 
    exit;
    //$arrayResult[] = 'Download Success';
}
```

And this is my js code :

```
$('#downloadLink').click(function(){
    var id = $('input:checkbox:checked').attr('id');
    var tobeSent = {
        'id' : id
    };
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'download.php',
        data:tobeSent,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data[0]);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

When I run this code nothing happens, and I get the following Console error in chrome :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is it you want to do, download a file or parse a JSON response?  Your ajax call implies the latter, while your PHP code implies the former.

Comment: @PatrickQ I want to download a file